# IPython noteboook doesn't recognize newer Anaconda distribution

Tags: python, ipython, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

I had to reinstall my Anaconda distribution for compatiability reasons. However even though the anaconda python works on terminal it doesn't work on ipython notebook. I think the ipython notebook remmebers some of the history so it loads up an earlier version of anaconda (which is replace by the new anaconda in the same location). So in my notebook the anaconda version looks like

```
import sys
print(sys.version)
print sys.executable
print sys.exc_clear()
2.7.10 |Anaconda 2.2.0 (64-bit)| (default, May 28 2015, 17:02:03) 
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-1)]
//anaconda/bin/python
```

But if I run in terminal I get

```
Python 2.7.10 |Anaconda 2.3.0 (64-bit)| (default, Sep 15 2015, 14:50:01)
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-1)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
Anaconda is brought to you by Continuum Analytics.
Please check out: http://continuum.io/thanks and https://anaconda.org
```

,noting the different in Anaconda version and release dates. 
I have already removed history.db in .ipython/profile_default/ and nbsignatures.db and restarted the Ipython notebook several times. What other things do I have to clear out in order for Ipython notebook to recognize the existence of a new distribution of anaconda? 
Thank you

Comment: How did you reinstall it? Did you completely remove `/anaconda`?